# Edit Shapefiles Attribute data in GeoServer Programatically

Tags: python, postgis, geoserver, shapefile

I'm rendering a shapefile using GeoServer and using OpenLayers library to render it in the web browser.

Now I have created the option of editing the attribute data in web browser. I want the edited data to get reflected back in the original shapefile.

What is the best method to edit shapefile programatically using Python. I'm quite new to GIS concepts. Or do i need to convert it to PostGIS format in-order to edit the attribute data using Python?

What are the best practices and way to go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all check out GeoServer Python scripting extension, [here](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Python+Scripting+Extension). it can give you some little tips and viewpoint.

if you want to modify your layer, try extension example that i have given.

```
from geoserver import Catalog
cat = Catalog('topp')
l = cat['states_shapefile']['states']
l.title = 'foo'
append(l.keywords, 'bar')
l.save()
```

beside this [pyshp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) is great for editing shapefiles with python, you can add this module to your code too.

and this can help you too.

1. [shp2geoserver.py](http://blog.geoserver.org/wp-content/uploads/shp2geoserver.py)
2. [shapefilebatch-cleaned.py](http://blog.geoserver.org/wp-content/uploads/shapefilebatch-cleaned.py)

   i hope it helps you...